# Why following vsnprintf crash on visual studio 2013/2015?

Tags: c++, memory

```
#include <string>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

void kekeTrace(const char* format, ...)
{
    char buff[1000] = { 0 };
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    vsnprintf(buff, 1000, format, argList);
    va_end(argList);
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> obj(new int(3));
    kekeTrace("%x,%d,%s\n", obj, 1, "w"); //crash
    kekeTrace("%x,%s\n", obj, "w"); // do not crash
    return 0;
}
```

The first call to kekeTrace would crash, but the second call does not. Why?

Comment: Undefined behavior? Must dereference it, `*obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines are undefined, so both may or may not crash, and may or may not output something.

Compilers are often smart enough these days to warn about unsupported types in format strings for `printf` et al, but since you're calling your own function the compiler has no idea what you're going to do with it.

You need to pass the underlying pointer: use `obj.get()`.